# Getting testing error " Test data contained a dictionary value for key 'category'"

Tags: testing, django-rest-framework

Writing test for a little API. Test for GET method working, but for create an error is being called. What could be the problem? i may guess the wrong data format is using.

```
class CoursesTest(APITestCase):

def setUp(self):

    self.course_url = reverse('course-group')
    User.objects.create(username='test111', password='123456')

def test_courses_post(self):
    data = {
    "name": "Blasssbla",
    "description": "blabla",
    "logo": "img",
    "category": {
        "name": "Baling",
        "imgpath": "img"
    },
    "contacts": [
        {
            "status": 1
        }
    ],
    "branches": [
        {
            "latitude": "2131ssss2321",
            "longitude": "12321321",
            "address": "Osssssh"
        }
    ]
}
    self.response = self.client.post(self.course_url, data)
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Error:

```
AssertionError: Test data contained a dictionary value for key 'category', but multipart uploads do not support nested data. You may want to consider using format='json' in this test case.
```

Answer (score 6):

If your test data is JSON, you should add `format="json"` to `self.client.post`.

```py
class CoursesTest(APITestCase):

def setUp(self):

    self.course_url = reverse('course-group')
    User.objects.create(username='test111', password='123456')

def test_courses_post(self):
    data = {
    "name": "Blasssbla",
    "description": "blabla",
    "logo": "img",
    "category": {
        "name": "Baling",
        "imgpath": "img"
    },
    "contacts": [
        {
            "status": 1
        }
    ],
    "branches": [
        {
            "latitude": "2131ssss2321",
            "longitude": "12321321",
            "address": "Osssssh"
        }
    ]
}
    self.response = self.client.post(self.course_url, data, format="json")
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a json as a body in test client post request, you have to add content_type='application/json' as a paramter in post.

```
import json

    class CoursesTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.course_url = reverse('course-group')
        User.objects.create(username='test111', password='123456')

    def test_courses_post(self):
        data = json.dump({
        "name": "Blasssbla",
        "description": "blabla",
        "logo": "img",
        "category": {
            "name": "Baling",
            "imgpath": "img"
        },
        "contacts": [
            {
                "status": 1
            }
        ],
        "branches": [
            {
                "latitude": "2131ssss2321",
                "longitude": "12321321",
                "address": "Osssssh"
            }
        ]
    })
        self.response = self.client.post(
          self.course_url, 
          data,     
          content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```